# Como validar dentro de una cadena en una variable final si existe un valor que venga de un excel en java

Tags: java

Buen dia amigos, el motivo de mi publicación es para preguntarles como puedo realizar una validación, actualmente tengo estas variables finales:

```
// USO CFDI - REGIMEN CASO 01
public static final String CODIGO_REGIMENFISCAL_01 = "601,603,606,612,620,621,622,623,624,625,626";

public static final String USOS_CFDI_01 = "G01,G02,G03,I01,I02,I03,I04,I05,I06,I07,I08";

// USO CFDI - REGIMEN CASO 02
public static final String CODIGO_REGIMENFISCAL_02 = "605,606,608,611,612,614,607,615,625";

public static final String USOS_CFDI_02 = "D01,D02,D03,D04,D05,D06,D07,D08,D09,D10";

// USO CFDI - REGIMEN CASO 03
public static final String CODIGO_REGIMENFISCAL_03 = "601,603,605,606,608,610,611,612,614,616,620,621,622,623,624,607,615,625,626";

public static final String USOS_CFDI_03 = "S01,CP01";

// USO CFDI - REGIMEN CASO 04
public static final String CODIGO_REGIMENFISCAL_04 = "605";

public static final String USOS_CFDI_04 = "CN01";
```

lo que quiero hacer es por ejemplo es que cuando cargo un archivo que me llegue con esta información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Valide en el catalogo que de las variables finales si se encuentra en alguna en caso de que no este mande un error con un mensaje, actualmente tengo esta validación pero no me está funcionando:

```
if(ValidadorCfdiRegimenFiscal.isRfcMoral(cuenta.getRfc()) && ValidadorCfdiRegimenFiscal.USOS_CFDI_03.contains(registroCargaMasivaCfdiRegimenFiscal.getCodigoCfdi())){                                 
                        registroCargaMasivaCfdiRegimenFiscal.setError(true);
                        registroCargaMasivaCfdiRegimenFiscal.setDescripcionError("El codigo de CFDI: "+registroCargaMasivaCfdiRegimenFiscal.getCodigoCfdi()+ "no es valido para el regimen fiscal " + registroCargaMasivaCfdiRegimenFiscal.getCodigoRegimenFiscal() + " para la cuenta: " +cuenta.getNumCuenta()+ "con rfc: "+cuenta.getRfc());
                        continue;
                    }
```

lo que quiero mas que nada es que quiero que se ejecute lo que está dentro de la validación dependiendo lo que me llegue en el archivo por ejemplo si quiero validar por su regimen fiscal que sea 606 y su codigo de uso cfdi sea I07, entonces este valla a la lista de la columna donde se encuentra el 606, siguiendo el ejemplo de la tabla vemos que `I07` no se encuentra en la columna donde está el 606 entonces ahora si, ejecute la validación que no se puede aplicar, lo que me percaté en la validación que estoy usando es que si le pongo el código `I07` dentro de la variable final `USOS_CFDI_03` esta si se va a ejecutar, lo que practicamente estoy haciendo lo contrario a como quiero realizarlo, podrían por favor ayudarme con esa validación? Se los agradecería mucho, si hay algo que no se esté entendiendo con gusto lo aclararé, de momento les agradezco.

Comment: Que es isRfcMoral() y Validador(), que valor tiene en tu ejemplo los valores que comparas?

Comment: Hola, esos los ocupo en otro proceso aunque por igual se puede omitir para este caso, aqui lo que se podría solo considerar es en donde está el contains que es el que creo está causando problemas en la validación

Comment: Los valores que ando validando en el validador es en los catalogos que vienen arriba public static final String USOS_CFDI_03 = "S01,CP01"; son los que puse en la foto de la tabla, uso de cfdi I07 al no encontrarse dentro de USOS_CFDI_03 quiero que se ejecute lo que viene en la validación del if ya que como mencioné no se encuentra, basicamente busco alguna manera de usar el contains pero en modo inverso ya que ya que este metodo regresa true ya que sino lo encuentra jamas va a entrar en el if, espero y me pueda dar entender, gracias